# Toggle button works on JSbin but not on flask server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, css

I have a code for toggle button written using HTML, CSS & Javascript. The aim of this code is to activate or select the href link when checkbox is checked. This works fine on JSBin.com.. But when i run on flask server on linux platform the checkbox unchecks immediately so that button toggles for just a second and returns to off position. I have no idea why this happens.

```js
$(function(){
      $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
      var item=$(this);    
      if(item.is(":checked"))
      {
           $('#On').get(0).click();
      }
      else
      {
           $('#Off').get(0).click();   
      }        
     });
    })
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#Off").hide();
        $("#On").click(function(){
        
            $("#On").hide();
            $("#Off").show();
        
        });
        $("#Off").click(function(){
            $("#Off").hide();
            $("#On").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <title>{{ title }}</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <body>

    <input type="checkbox" > <br/>
      <h1>
          <a href="/On" id="On" class="">ON</a>
      </h1>
      <h1>
          <a href="/Off" id="Off" class="off_class">OFF</a>
      </h1>
    </body> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#` in `href` instead, and code is working fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      $('#On').get(0).click();
    } else {
      $('#Off').get(0).click();
    }
  });
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$("#Off").hide();
  $("#On").click(function() {

    $("#On").hide();
    $("#Off").show();

  });
  $("#Off").click(function() {
    $("#Off").hide();
    $("#On").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"> <br/>
<h1>
  <a href="#" id="On" class="">ON</a>
</h1>
<h1>
  <a href="#" id="Off" class="off_class">OFF</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Now the code is working fine.. But the python flask fails to detect the state from href tag. If i use '/ ' flask identifies the state from html and executes some conditions but on UI the toggle button not working. On another hand, If i use '#' the toggle button works fine but flask is not reading href state. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Actually I don't know python, so I'm not able to help you.